# Question regarding transitive group action.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Group action $(G,X)$ is transitive. I know in this case for any $x,y \in X$ we have $Stab(x)=j Stab(y) j^{-1}$ for some $j\in G.$Then why do we have $$\sum_{g \in Stab(x)} \vert Fix(g) \vert = \sum_{g \in Stab(y)} \vert Fix(g) \vert$$ for any $x,y \in X$?
I just find it not very intuitive. Any ideas?

Comment: Simply because f $g\in Stab(x)$, $t\in Fix(g)$, then $j^{-1}gj \in Stab(y)$, and $j^{-1}\cdot t \in Fix(j^{-1}gj)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that $\text{Stab}(x)=j\cdot\text{Stab}(y)\cdot j^{-1}$ for some $j$, you can probably look at the proof of that statement and find there the information that $g$ fixes $y$ iff $jgj^{-1}$ fixes $jy$. (Alternatively, you can just prove this directly.) In other words, the fixed-points of $jgj^{-1}$ are just $j$ of the fixed-points of $g$; in particular, $jgj^{-1}$ has the same number of fixed-points as $g$ does. That is $|\text{Fix}(jgj^{-1})|=|\text{Fix}(g)|$.  Now sum that equation over all $g\in\text{Stab}(y)$, and you'll get the equation you want.